# AlertDialog SingleChoiceItems not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to make a SingleChoiceItems AlertDialog with an OK and Cancel button which gives the user the option on a onItemLongClick from a ListView to 1.view the user's profile 2.send the user a message and 3.delete the user from the friends list.

I haven't done option 1 and 2 yet but I'm trying to make option 3 right now in which I included the Database delete method and a toast that says "friend removed" but when I select Option 3 and hit ok that row does not get deleted or I see the Toast saying the user was deleted.Here is my code for the Activity I'm using the Dialog.

```
public class PlayAFriend extends ListActivity {
    DBAdapter DBAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_items);
        final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        DBAdapter = db.open();
        ListView FriendLV = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        final Cursor friendslist = db.GetAllFriends();
        String[] from = new String[] { "FRIENDS" }; // your column/columns here
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textview_friends };

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        ListAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_items, friendslist, from, to, 0);
        FriendLV.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        FriendLV.setLongClickable(true);

        FriendLV.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
                public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
                    super(context, friendslist, flags);
                    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                }

                LayoutInflater inflater;

                @Override
                public void bindView(View view, Context context,
                        Cursor friendslist) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int row_id = ((com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.DBAdapter) friendslist)
                            .get("_id");

                }

                @Override
                public View newView(Context context, Cursor friendslist,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent,
                            false);
                    bindView(v, context, friendslist);
                    return v;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showDialog(arg2);
                return false;

            }
        });

    }

    public void OnButtonClick(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(
                "com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.Fightattacker"));
    }

    String[] items = { "View Profile", "Send Message", "Remove Friend" };

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(final int id) {
        final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        db.open();
        switch (id) {
        case 0:
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setTitle("Select an Option")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(items, id,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int choice) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }

                    )
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int choice) {

                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            if (choice == 0) {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                        "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                            } else if (choice == 1) {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                        "Test2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();

                            } else if (choice == 2) {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                        "Friend Removed",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                final TextView friends = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_friends);
                                String deletedfriend = friends
                                        .getText().toString();

                                db.DeleteFriends(deletedfriend);

                            }

                        }

                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int choice) {

                        }
                    })

                    .create();

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Clear the database
        DBAdapter.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Please format your code, it's unreadable.

Comment: It is formatted I believe

Comment: It's not. Do you know how I know? I have eyes.

Comment: @ChristopherPerry is it better now?

Comment: No. Make it look like how it would in your IDE. If people can't easily distinguish which braces surround what, they won't answer your question.

Comment: There is no toast when you click OK?

Comment: @HoanNguyen no there was no toast

Comment: @ChristopherPerry I'm going to try to reformat my code it looks fine on my ide

Comment: It doesn't look fine in your post.

Comment: Put a toast in choice 0 and 1 and choose choice 2 and see if a toast pop up.

Comment: @HoanNguyen didn't work

Comment: No toast anywhere? how about choosing choice 0 or 1?

Comment: @ChristopherPerry formatted it

Comment: @HoanNguyen no If I was to put it in the SingleChoiceItems it would show when I highlight but not when I click OK in other words I want to have my selection work via the positive OK button

Comment: @Cranosaur Why don't you check the developer site has some examples http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for the link I'm reading it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the choice when select a radio button, the other int parameter in the button does not represent the choice. 
Make `int mChoice;` a class member

```
public class PlayAFriend extends ListActivity {
DBAdapter DBAdapter;
int mChoice;
......
......

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(final int id) {

    final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    switch (id) {
    case 0:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setTitle("Select an Option")
        .setSingleChoiceItems(items, id,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int choice) {
                mChoice = choice; // save the choice

            }
        }

                )
                .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int choice) {

                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        if (mChoice == 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        } else if (mChoice == 1) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    "Test2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();

                        } else if (mChoice == 2) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    "Friend Removed",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            final TextView friends = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_friends);
                            String deletedfriend = friends
                                    .getText().toString();

                            db.DeleteFriends(deletedfriend);

                        }

                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int choice) {

                    }
                })

                .create();

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting errors it whats me to change to final but when I do it it says "The final local variable mChoice cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type".

Comment: change int mChoice; to final int mChoice;

Comment: I did but now it says "The final local variable mChoice cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type" and choices 0-2 needs to initialize variables

Comment: make int mChoice a PlayAFriend class member.

Comment: How would I do this?I don't have the option

Comment: why just right after DBAdapter DBAdapter; the next line put int mChoice;